# Href problem with IE and Edge that does not redirect

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, .net-core, microsoft-edge, razor-pages

I'm having a problem with a href that does not work on Edge or IE, but works perfectly on other browsers.

To explain the operation, I have a form with 3 dropdownlist. The user must choose a value from each of the lists to activate the a href. The content of the href is dynamized in jQuery according to the choices made in the list. The dynamization works correctly but once the link activated, when I click on it does not happen.

By default my link is created as below:

```
<a href="#" id="buttonSearchPro" disabled="disabled" style="cursor: default;">
    <input role="button" class="btn btnAction" value="Validate" />
</a>
```

Once the user has chosen a value in the 3 lists I call the following jQuery method:

```
var typeProSearch = $('#typeProSearch').val();
var typeSearch = $('#typeSearch').val();
var choiceDepartment = $('#choiceDepartment').val();
var hrefListPro = "/ProfessionalList/Index_ProfessionalList?typeProSearch=" +
    typeProSearch +
    "&typeSearch=" +
    typeSearch +
    "&department=" +
    choiceDepartment +
    "&townName=all";
$('#buttonSearchPro').attr('href', hrefListPro);
$('#buttonSearchPro').prop('disabled', false);
```

After that if I inspect the item, I have my URL in the href but when I click on the link nothing happens. Should we add something for the href to be taken into account under Edge?

Comment: You may want to consider wrapping the values coming from text boxes with `encodeURIComponent` to ensure they work in a URL.

Comment: What does the rendered anchor tag look like? Like, if you inspect the element and grab the full HTML for the tag?

Comment: I found the problem. To get a visual close to a button, we put an input in the tags a. However, edge does not support having an input in a.
We removed the input and everything is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following method to solve this issue:

method 1: add the type property (type = "button") for the input element. Please modify your code as below:

```
<a href="#" id="buttonSearchPro" disabled="disabled" style="cursor: default;">
    <input role="button" type="button" class="btn btnAction" value="Validate" />
</a>
```

method 2: using window.location.href redirect to the page. Code as below:

```
var typeProSearch = $('#typeProSearch').val();
var typeSearch = $('#typeSearch').val();
var choiceDepartment = $('#choiceDepartment').val();
var hrefListPro = "/ProfessionalList/Index_ProfessionalList?typeProSearch=" +
    typeProSearch +
    "&typeSearch=" +
    typeSearch +
    "&department=" +
    choiceDepartment +
    "&townName=all";
$('#buttonSearchPro').attr('href', hrefListPro);
$('#buttonSearchPro').prop('disabled', false);
//redirect to the new page.
window.location.href = hrefListPro;
```